# Find a string inside the column name using MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a select query for searching string in the particular column.

For example :

```
+----+------+-------------------------------+
| id | name |           alternate           |
+----+------+-------------------------------+
| 1  | Test | Test,Tests,test,tests,te,test |
| 2  | Demo | Demo.demo,dem,Dem             |
+----+------+-------------------------------+
```

etc...

I just want to write a query for checking the submitted value name in the column name alternate

For example : I will submit the name test and it should check exists or not with the column name alternate that contains

Comment: `WHERE column LIKE '%string%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)

```
$query = SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE FIND_IN_SET('test', alternate);

if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
   //if test was found
} else {
   // test not found
}
```

for more information [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query in `mysql`:

```
SELECT ID,NAME,ALTERNATE,
CASE WHEN (FIND_IN_SET(name, alternate) > 0)
THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END RESULT FROM TABLE1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ced53/4)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select count(*) as total from tablename where alternate LIKE %test%
```

if the `total` value returned is greater than zero then string test exist in `alternate` column

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is using the String function INSTR to check whether the Substring exists in the String or not. You can even pass a variable in Substring and String to check.

`SELECT IF(INSTR(alternate,'test')! = 0,'Exists', 'Not Exists') as SearchResult FROM table;`

Documentation can be found at:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr